# How can i get the conract status after DocuSign esignature

Tags: docusignapi, docusignconnect

I'm using DocuSign API to sign a contract.
All it's okay, the platform provides me with the signed contract, but my problem here is how to know from the platform if the contract is signed or not yet.
I need that information to update the contract status in my application. Can anyone please provide me with a useful idea?

Answer (score 2):

Please keep in mind that polling us for status updates is not a good practice. It's best to use DocuSign Connect and provide a webhook that we can call when there is a status update on the envelope. For more information, please see: https://developers.docusign.com/platform/webhooks/connect/

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming your are working wit the rest api, so you can use this endpoint to identify the status of envelope
https://<base_url>/restapi/v2.1/accounts/<account_id>/envelopes/<envelope_id>

for SDK you can refer https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/get-envelope-information/ this link

Comment: sorry what should I put in base_url exactly ?

Answer (score 1):

Beyond what @Nima said:

1. Polling DocuSign for status is `not allowed` more frequently than once every 15 minutes.
2. Use the DocuSign webhook system to learn that an envelope has been signed/completed. See this [blog post](https://www.docusign.com/blog/dsdev-webhook-listeners-part-4) You do `not` need to change your firewall to receive the notifications.